# Why are my computer graphics better on battery?

Tags: graphics-card, battery

When I was playing games, I noticed lag spikes, but only when my computer was plugged in. I tried configuring all the power options available, but I was not successful. I know it was the graphics that had been affected, because I tested a non-graphics program both on and off the charger. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have "switchable graphics"? (see http://superuser.com/questions/276763/what-is-switchable-graphics-cards-in-laptops )

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to put it down to the environment and your CPU.

Depending on your computer, the power saving mode likely throttles your CPU performance to save on power back to a less extreme usage state. On wall-power mode, I'd say it lets it throttle up because it no longer cares about power, but then this causes it to overheat which in turn triggers thermal throttling. Thermal throttling has been responsible for a lot of these sort of unexpected issues.

Download a performance monitoring tool (or use the one built in to windows) and watch the frequency at which your CPU and GPU are operating, as well as the temperatures. With that information, you'll be able to more accurately find the issue, or at least help us help you find it.

Either way, you need to elaborate a bit more on the circumstances, ie. how often it lags, at what stage of gameplay (after 1sec or 1hr) etc. The more info, the better answer people can give you.

Comment: That is a pretty good theory for the odd situation presented.  and supplies a testing method for discovery. going from a low balanced but not overheating, to a spikey throttling stepping off the high speed when the temps get too high .  Temperature monitor and testing with benchmark or torture programs that push certian aspects of the hardware.  or temp monitoring and testing reality with an eye on stepping and gpu charateristics