# How to identify manipulated specs on laptop

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, specifications

I bought a new laptop and I installed the drivers for NVIDIA GT920M and Intel HD6000. I can find both the graphics under Display Adapters in the Device Manager on Windows 7. 
I have my doubts and would like to know if the information on Device Manager could be manipulated too. FYI, I did a clean install on the laptop. It shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: how exactly would the devices in device manager be manipulated?  Windows only reads what the hardware identifies itself as.

Comment: @Ramhound by any other means, like in the hardware itself. maybe an 820 manipulated to look like 920.

Comment: @FrankThomas Manipulated for better sales. It has been happening recently esp. on laptops bought online.

Comment: you will have to open it up and inspect the hardware. if it has been modified to provide a fake device ID string, then they have modified the device's firmware, so there is no surefire software way to tell, unless they made a mistake. you might want to confirm the device ID string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @user1928108 give some specific examples of manipulated hardware (links showing proof), or it this just another internet rumor.

Comment: @user1928108 - The firmware would have to be updated also.  If that happens then neither visual inspection or software could tell the difference, provided, there are no visual differences between the two cards ( but there is ) so this an actual problem you face?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have 2 Display Adapters is because that laptop has a feature called switchable graphics. The specs have mot been manipulated on that laptop.

[See this link](https://superuser.com/questions/276763/what-is-switchable-graphics-cards-in-laptops)